# query from multiple tables?

Tags: database, oracle

Hi I recently started self-studying Oracle SQL, and am stuck in the following problem. I would be glad if I can be guided on how to approach the solution to these type of problem.

We have a Database.
Database consists of following tables:

Table route_info contains the descriptions of routes on which monorails used to travel.

```
route_info(route_no INTEGER, source STRING, destination STRING, length INTEGER, departs TIME, arrives TIME, cost INTEGER);

+----------+----------+-------------+--------+----------+----------+------+
| route_no | source   | destination | length | departs  | arrives  | cost |
+----------+----------+-------------+--------+----------+----------+------+
|     1462 | Banglore | Delhi       |   1516 | 13:00:00 | 15:00:00 | 4500 |
|     4456 | Gwalior  | Delhi       |    543 | 05:05:06 | 04:55:24 |  546 |
|     4524 | Banglore | Delhi       |   1516 | 04:44:00 | 13:00:45 | 1200 |
|     7490 | Banglore | Gwalior     |   1343 | 01:16:17 | 17:07:08 | 1400 |
|     7890 | Agra     | Gwalior     |    343 | 01:15:41 | 07:07:08 |  400 |
+----------+----------+-------------+--------+----------+----------+------+
```

Table monorail contains the information about each monorail.

```
monorail(rid INTEGER, rname STRING, runningrange INTEGER);

+------+---------------+--------------+
| rid  | rname         | runningrange |
+------+---------------+--------------+
| 4454 | Mark Jung Exp |          300 |
| 1234 | Speedester    |          454 |
| 2134 | Monstor       |         4054 |
| 7334 | Father        |         1051 |
| 4444 | Supreme       |         3023 |
| 1444 | Grain         |         3023 |
+------+---------------+--------------+
```

Table employee contains information of all the employees in the organization (including drivers of monorails).

```
employee(eid INTEGER, ename STRING, salary INTEGER);

+------+--------+--------+
| eid  | ename  | salary |
+------+--------+--------+
|  101 | Nusrat |    100 |
|  234 | emp1   |   5050 |
|  323 | emp2   |   7050 |
|  314 | emp3   |  10050 |
|  541 | emp4   |   9010 |
|  432 | emp5   |  12345 |
|  123 | Kabir  |    400 |
|  555 | Raheem |    235 |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Table assigned contains the data about which monorail is driven by which employee. This can be a many-to-many relation.

```
assigned(eid INTEGER, rid INTEGER);

+------+------+
| eid  | rid  |
+------+------+
|  101 | 4454 |
|  234 | 1234 |
|  323 | 1234 |
|  314 | 1234 |
|  314 | 2134 |
|  541 | 2134 |
|  123 | 7334 |
|  101 | 4444 |
|  101 | 1444 |
+------+------+
```

We are given the following guidelines

- Make all necessary assumptions.
- String comparison is case-insensitive.
- Always return result in increasing order of output.

Now we need to write an Oracle SQL query for this: 
For all monorails whose "runningrange" is greater than 500, find the id of rail ("rid") and sum of salary of all drivers assigned to this rail.

Comment: Seems like a simple `inner join` with `group by` and `sum`... What have you tried so far?

Comment: So, you want us to do it for you? Show the query you tried, what problems you have with it and maybe errors you get.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have studied "group by" , "inner join" , but this is the first question I tackled with so many attributes. Do we need to normalize it or something? I was too stumbled to have so many attributes to handle. That's when I thought if anyone could help me out here on how to approach this with a solution.

Comment: I think that you should spend some time actually learning SQL.
The query you need is fairly simple and since you do not know how to write it, points out that you lack the essential knowledge about SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it down to smaller pieces will make it easier to understand:
Start by getting all the monorails whose "runningrange" is greater than 500:

```
SELECT rid
FROM monorail 
WHERE runningrange > 500
```

Then add the `inner join` to the `assigned` table:

```
SELECT m.rid
FROM monorail m
INNER JOIN assigned a ON(m.rid = a.rid)
WHERE runningrange > 500
```

Then add another `inner join` to the `employee` table:

```
SELECT m.rid
FROM monorail m
INNER JOIN assigned a ON(m.rid = a.rid)
INNER JOIN employee e ON(a.eid = e.eid)
WHERE runningrange > 500
```

And finally add the `group by` and `sum`.

```
SELECT m.rid, SUM(salary) 
FROM monorail m
INNER JOIN assigned a ON(m.rid = a.rid)
INNER JOIN employee e ON(a.eid = e.eid)
WHERE runningrange > 500
GROUP BY m.rid
ORDER BY SUM(salary)
```

Comment: Wow, great answer. But, I would not write the query for the OP until he show a little effort for the work he is doing.

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 
This gives this error. I am sure I am lacking something here. What is it? :\

Comment: @Zohan, See, what I told you. He asked the question in order to get the solution without effort. He is trying with trial-error approach, instead of learning the basics of the SQL and platform.

Comment: @Dusan I am obliged by your concern, but I believe in learning from examples. I will obviously study the topics given by Zohan, but firstly I just checked if this is working. I don't see any wrong in that. Also, I am not doing this for any homework or something- I am employed, and just wished to learn Databases, since I wish to enter IT industry. :)

Comment: Then spend some time reading zillion of examples, tutorials and books available online, instead of asking question that makes your wok done.

Comment: I'm not an oracle guy myself, I'm usually working with sql server, but based on the error you got I'm guessing oracle is expecting every sql statement to end with a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: @Dusan I usually don't bother answering [this type of rtfm questions,](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293931/should-one-answer-terribly-poor-questions/293966#293966) and actually, I've started writing this answer as a comment to the question, but realized it would be better as an answer since it can have code examples.